# Lógica de programação para montar Rede trinária

Tags: algoritmo

Não estou conseguindo montar a rede trinária abaixo:

[image: rede trinária]

A lógica é a seguinte:

- Faço meu cadastro no sistema e é gerado um link de indicação;
- Ocupa-se a 1ª, 2ª e 3ª posição (pode ser cadastros através do meu
  link de indicação ou por derramamento, ou seja, de outro link);
- 4º **cadastro** vai para a **primeira posição disponível de sua 1ª posição** já ocupada na 1ª classe;
- 5º **cadastro** vai para a **primeira posição disponível de sua 2ª posição** já ocupada na 1ª classe;
- 6º **cadastro** vai para a **primeira posição disponível de sua 3ª posição** já ocupada na 1ª classe;
- **Segue-se assim em todas as classes**, sempre distribuindo o cadastro de forma igualitária em rede;

## O problema

De acordo com a imagem, quando o 8º **cadastro** for realizado, ele **não poderá** ocupar a 7ª **posição** da 2ª classe. Esta posição já foi ocupada por um cadastro direto.

Nesse momento, o sistema deve procurar a próxima posição disponível na 2ª classe.

Sempre terá que preencher as classe/linha para começar outra classe.

Não quero a programação, quero a lógica para montar essa rede.

Comment: Por "lógica", entendo que você queira dizer "algoritmo"? É isso?

Comment: Sim, o algoritmo que não estou conseguindo montar.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o algoritmo seria algo assim:

```
1. Se o último nível da árvore estiver cheio então:
2.     Pendure o novo nó abaixo do primeiro item do último nível, criando um novo nível.
3. Senão:
4.     Escolha um grupo X no último nível que tenha o menor número de nós dentre os grupos no mesmo nível. Em caso de empate, pegue o grupo mais a direita destes.
5.     Pendure o novo item no final grupo X.
6. Fim se
```